# Condense null check for Linq statement in razor page to 1 line

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection with an IEnumerable interface in a Razor page with a variable number of items.

To ensure when the number of items is below 5 I don't try and get the 5th item in the collection, I have a check like this:

```
@if (Model.MyItems.Count() > 5)
{
    @Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault().Title
}
```

So if there are fewer than 5 items in the collection it doesn't try and display it.

Is there a way I can do all of this in one Linq statement - something like this:

```
@Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault().Title.ReturnIfExistsElseReturnEmptyString()
```

It would make the Razor code far more elegant and terse.

I can find nothing on Google - I'm not even sure what to look for I'm relatively new to Linq.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably use *[Null Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)* `?.` *[Null Coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)* `??`

```
@Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault()?.Title ?? "";
```

---

**Null-conditional Operators**

> Used to test for null before performing a member access `?.` or index
>   `?[` operation. These operators help you write less code to handle
>   null checks, especially for descending into data structures.

**Null Coalesce ?? Operator**

> The `??` operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns
>   the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns
>   the right hand operand.

---

**Further reading**

[null-coalescing](https://www.dotnetperls.com/null-coalescing)

---

## Update

As noted in a comment by *Ron Beyer*

> The OP's issue is also that there may not be 5 elements in MyItems, so
>   the Skip(5) may return an empty enumerable. It is worth noting that
>   Skip doesn't error out there, but returns empty

Which is to say, there may not be 5 elements in your list. Although the above code will work fine and happily return an *Empty String* (or what ever you choose), it doesn't give you any indication that there were less than 5 elements. if you need to know this you would have to do it in 2 lines.

```
@if (Model.MyItems.Count() > 5)
{
    @Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault()?.Title ?? ""
}
else
{
   // blarg there is less then 5
}
```

Comment: Skip does error out "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." if I skip(5) when there are fewer than 5 elements though?!

Comment: Try putting a question mark directly after the skip

Comment: It's a null conditional operator, click the link on the top of my post, it will explain better also the other link mid way down

Comment: If I put a . after FirstOrDefault() I get intellisense for Title. If I do so after ?. I get no intellisense and the page just renders the text '?.Title' in the page. Not working with Razor perhaps?! (?? ""; is also output to the page)

Comment: @niico  Is there a chance my items is null. Yes this coukd be just razor... `Skip(5). ?FiestOrDefault()?. Title?? ""` dosnt work?

Comment: The problem happens - outputting ?.Title as text - whether the collection is null, has fewer than 5 items or more than 5 items.

Comment: Are you asking me to try "?FirstOrDefault()?.Title"? That outputs "System.Linq.Enumerable+<SkipIterator>__..... text to the page

Comment: I'm on my phone and can't test, but I can have a look in couple if hours, it might just be a razor limitation

Comment: Yeah sorry my comments arnt formatting correctly, basically?. After things

Comment: This is the best I can come up with:                             @(Model.MyItems.Count() > 5 ? Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault().Title : "")

Answer (score 2):

```
@Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault()?.Title
```

`FirstOrDefault()` will return null in that case so using the null-conditional `?.` gives you null for the title in that case.

If you want something else for the string in that case then add on a null-coalescing, so e.g. for an empty string:

```
@Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault()?.Title ?? ""
```

Or:

```
@Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault()?.Title ?? "Untitled"
```

Etc.

Comment: The OP's issue is also that there may not be 5 elements in `MyItems`, so the `Skip(5)` may return an empty enumerable. It is worth noting that Skip doesn't error out there, but returns empty.

Comment: @RonBeyer that's not their issue as when `Skip` returns empty, `FirstOrDefault` returns null. Their problem was not throwing on that null.

Comment: Also this doesn't work - I get no intellisense and "?.Title" is just output as text in the page: "@Model.MyItems.Skip(5).FirstOrDefault()?.Title"

Comment: And you're using at least C# 6?